# Splix invalid PPD file version

Tags: cups

I have a Samsung M2020 printer and it is connected to CUPS, with a Linux Samsung M2020 driver. When I want to print a test file, this error appears: `SpliX Invalid PPD file version: 2.0.0 but the PPD file is designed for SpliX V. 1.3`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a proper printer driver for it. The link is: https://gitlab.com/ScumCoder/splix/-/blob/patches/splix/ppd/m2020.ppd